# Handling multiple file uploads with Plack

Tags: perl, plack

Trying handling multiple file uploads with Plack.

My form:

```
<form id="file_upload" action="savefile" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file[]" multiple>
<button>upload</button>
</form>
```

Selected two files, called: `x1` and `x2`. The `Data::Dumper` result of the:

```
my $u = $req->uploads;
```

is

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
    'file[]' => bless( {
         'headers' => bless( {
              'content-disposition' => 'form-data; name="file[]"; filename="x2"',
              'content-type' => 'application/octet-stream',
              '::std_case' => {
                   'content-disposition' => 'Content-Disposition'
              }
         }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
         'filename' => 'x2',
         'tempname' => '/var/folders/7l/nhyscwy14bjb_sxr_t2gynpm0000gn/T/7vt04wIrne',
         'size' => 146
    }, 'Plack::Request::Upload' )
}, 'Hash::MultiValue' );
```

So, it contains only the second file `x2`, but when checked the folder `/var/folders/7l/nhyscwy14bjb_sxr_t2gynpm0000gn/T/` it contains *both files* uploaded.

The question is how i can get *both* files to the script, not ony the last one?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
for my $upload ($req->upload('file[]')) {
  $upload->filename;
}
```

You can also call `@uploads = $req->uploads->get_all('file[]')` to get multiple values.

See [`perldoc Plack::Request`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Plack%3a%3aRequest) (and [`Hash::MultiValue`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Hash%3a%3aMultiValue)) for more details.

The reason you don't see them in Data::Dumper is that Hash::MultiValue uses a technique called inside-out object, to save alternate values for a given key.